# Copying Data from multiple workbooks -> Into One Worksheet (continuous data)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro created by my predecessor that I run on a monthly basis. However, it does take a while to get through, and I would like to clean it up for efficiency please.

It copies data from multiple Workbooks:

`Wholesale\Reporting\Market6 Scorecard\Templates\52 Wk Data.csv`

`Wholesale\Reporting\Market6 Scorecard\Templates\26 Wk Data.csv`

etc..

and pastes to the Destination Worksheet:
`Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("COMBINED")`

Here is the macro, and I keep thinking there are duplicate variables. But maybe there's a reason that I don't understand yet. Thoughts?

```
Sub DataPaste()

'Turn Off Screen Updates
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Weekly Division Tab:

'Open Weekly Data Workbook
    Workbooks.Open "O:\Wholesale\Reporting\Market6 Scorecard\Templates\Weekly Data.csv"

'Remove Current Data
    Dim aDataPaste As Worksheet
        Set aDataPaste = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("Weekly Division")
    
    Dim TemplateLastRow As Long
        TemplateLastRow = aDataPaste.Cells(aDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    
        Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("Weekly Division").Range("A1:A12").ClearContents
        Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("Weekly Division").Range("A15:Z" & TemplateLastRow).ClearContents
    
'Copy Title Information
        Workbooks("Weekly Data.csv").Worksheets("Weekly Data").Range("A1:A12").Copy Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("Weekly Division").Range("A1:A12")
    
'Copy data
    Dim aTemplate As Worksheet
    Dim DataLastRow As Long
        Set aTemplate = Workbooks("Weekly Data.csv").Worksheets("Weekly Data")
        DataLastRow = aTemplate.Cells(aTemplate.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    
        Workbooks("Weekly Data.csv").Worksheets("Weekly Data").Range("A17:I" & DataLastRow).Copy Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("Weekly Division").Range("A15:I" & DataLastRow)
    
        Workbooks("Weekly Data.csv").Worksheets("Weekly Data").Range("J17:N" & DataLastRow).Copy Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("Weekly Division").Range("L15:P" & DataLastRow)
    
        Workbooks("Weekly Data.csv").Worksheets("Weekly Data").Range("O17:P" & DataLastRow).Copy Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("Weekly Division").Range("V15:W" & DataLastRow)
   
'Close Weekly Data Workbook
    Workbooks("Weekly Data.csv").Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    
'Combined Tab:
    'Remove Current Data
        Dim bDataPaste As Worksheet
            Set bDataPaste = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("COMBINED")
    
        Dim bTemplateLastRow As Long
            bTemplateLastRow = bDataPaste.Cells(bDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
        
        Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("COMBINED").Range("A5:U" & bTemplateLastRow).ClearContents
        
'Copy 52 Wk Data
    Workbooks.Open "O:\Wholesale\Reporting\Market6 Scorecard\Templates\52 Wk Data.csv"
    
    Dim cWkData As Worksheet
    Dim cDataPaste As Worksheet
            Set cWkData = Workbooks("52 Wk Data.csv").Worksheets("52 Wk Data")
            Set cDataPaste = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("COMBINED")
            
    Dim cTemplateLastRow As Long
    Dim cCopyLastRow As Long
            cTemplateLastRow = cDataPaste.Cells(cDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            cCopyLastRow = cWkData.Cells(cWkData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            
            cWkData.Range("A18:H" & cCopyLastRow).Copy cDataPaste.Range("B5:I" & bTemplateLastRow)
            cWkData.Range("I18:R" & cCopyLastRow).Copy cDataPaste.Range("L5:U" & cTemplateLastRow)
            
    'Add Dates
        Dim cTemplateLastRowb As Long
        Dim cTemplateLastRowc As Long
            cTemplateLastRowb = cDataPaste.Cells(cDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            cTemplateLastRowc = cDataPaste.Cells(cDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    
        Dim cFirstRow As Range
        Dim cLastRow As Range
            Set cFirstRow = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("COMBINED").Range("A5")
            Set cLastRow = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("COMBINED").Range("A" & cTemplateLastRowb)
            Range(cFirstRow, cLastRow).Formula = "=concatenate(""Latest 52 Wks - Ending "",left(right('Weekly Division'!$A$4,24),23))"
        
    Workbooks("52 Wk Data.csv").Close SaveChanges:=False
    
'Copy 26 Wk Data
    Workbooks.Open "O:\Wholesale\Reporting\Market6 Scorecard\Templates\26 Wk Data.csv"
    
    Dim dWkData As Worksheet
    Dim dDataPaste As Worksheet
            Set dWkData = Workbooks("26 Wk Data.csv").Worksheets("26 Wk Data")
            Set dDataPaste = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("COMBINED")
            
    Dim dTemplateLastRow As Long
    Dim dCopyLastRow As Long
            dTemplateLastRow = dDataPaste.Cells(dDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            dCopyLastRow = dWkData.Cells(dWkData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            
            dWkData.Range("A18:H" & dCopyLastRow).Copy dDataPaste.Range("B" & dTemplateLastRow)
            dWkData.Range("I18:R" & dCopyLastRow).Copy dDataPaste.Range("L" & dTemplateLastRow)
            
    'Add Dates
        Dim dTemplateLastRowb As Long
        Dim dTemplateLastRowc As Long
                dTemplateLastRowb = dDataPaste.Cells(dDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                dTemplateLastRowc = dDataPaste.Cells(dDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    
    Dim dFirstRow As Range
    Dim dLastRow As Range
                Set dFirstRow = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("COMBINED").Range("A" & cTemplateLastRowc)
                Set dLastRow = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("COMBINED").Range("A" & dTemplateLastRowb)
                Range(dFirstRow, dLastRow).Formula = "=concatenate(""Latest 26 Wks - Ending "",left(right('Weekly Division'!$A$4,24),23))"
                
    Workbooks("26 Wk Data.csv").Close SaveChanges:=False
    
'Copy 13 Wk Data
    Workbooks.Open "O:\Wholesale\Reporting\Market6 Scorecard\Templates\13 Wk Data.csv"
    
    Dim eWkData As Worksheet
    Dim eDataPaste As Worksheet
            Set eWkData = Workbooks("13 Wk Data.csv").Worksheets("13 Wk Data")
            Set eDataPaste = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("COMBINED")
            
    Dim eTemplateLastRow As Long
    Dim eCopyLastRow As Long
            eTemplateLastRow = eDataPaste.Cells(eDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            eCopyLastRow = eWkData.Cells(eWkData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            
            eWkData.Range("A18:H" & eCopyLastRow).Copy eDataPaste.Range("B" & eTemplateLastRow)
            eWkData.Range("I18:R" & eCopyLastRow).Copy eDataPaste.Range("L" & eTemplateLastRow)
            
        'Add Dates
            Dim eTemplateLastRowb As Long
            Dim eTemplateLastRowc As Long
                eTemplateLastRowb = eDataPaste.Cells(eDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                eTemplateLastRowc = eDataPaste.Cells(eDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            
            Dim eFirstRow As Range
            Dim eLastRow As Range
                Set eFirstRow = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("COMBINED").Range("A" & dTemplateLastRowc)
                Set eLastRow = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("COMBINED").Range("A" & eTemplateLastRowb)
                Range(eFirstRow, eLastRow).Formula = "=concatenate(""Latest 13 Wks - Ending "",left(right('Weekly Division'!$A$4,24),23))"
    
    Workbooks("13 Wk Data.csv").Close SaveChanges:=False
    
'Copy 4 Wk Data
    Workbooks.Open "O:\Wholesale\Reporting\Market6 Scorecard\Templates\4 Wk Data.csv"
    
    Dim fWkData As Worksheet
    Dim fDataPaste As Worksheet
            Set fWkData = Workbooks("4 Wk Data.csv").Worksheets("4 Wk Data")
            Set fDataPaste = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("COMBINED")
            
    Dim fTemplateLastRow As Long
    Dim fCopyLastRow As Long
            fTemplateLastRow = fDataPaste.Cells(fDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            fCopyLastRow = fWkData.Cells(fWkData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            
            fWkData.Range("A18:H" & fCopyLastRow).Copy fDataPaste.Range("B" & fTemplateLastRow)
            fWkData.Range("I18:R" & fCopyLastRow).Copy fDataPaste.Range("L" & fTemplateLastRow)
            
        'Add Dates
            Dim fTemplateLastRowb As Long
            Dim fTemplateLastRowc As Long
                fTemplateLastRowb = fDataPaste.Cells(fDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                fTemplateLastRowc = fDataPaste.Cells(fDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
                
            Dim fFirstRow As Range
            Dim fLastRow As Range
                Set fFirstRow = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("COMBINED").Range("A" & eTemplateLastRowc)
                Set fLastRow = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("COMBINED").Range("A" & fTemplateLastRowb)
                Range(fFirstRow, fLastRow).Formula = "=concatenate(""Latest 04 Wks - Ending "",left(right('Weekly Division'!$A$4,24),23))"
        
        Workbooks("4 Wk Data.csv").Close SaveChanges:=False
        
'Copy YTD Data
    Workbooks.Open "O:\Wholesale\Reporting\Market6 Scorecard\Templates\YTD Data.csv"
    
    Dim gWkData As Worksheet
    Dim gDataPaste As Worksheet
            Set gWkData = Workbooks("YTD Data.csv").Worksheets("YTD Data")
            Set gDataPaste = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("COMBINED")
            
    Dim gTemplateLastRow As Long
    Dim gCopyLastRow As Long
            gTemplateLastRow = gDataPaste.Cells(gDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            gCopyLastRow = gWkData.Cells(gWkData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            
            gWkData.Range("A18:H" & gCopyLastRow).Copy gDataPaste.Range("B" & gTemplateLastRow)
            gWkData.Range("I18:R" & gCopyLastRow).Copy gDataPaste.Range("L" & gTemplateLastRow)
            
        'Add Dates
            Dim gTemplateLastRowb As Long
            Dim gTemplateLastRowc As Long
                gTemplateLastRowb = gDataPaste.Cells(gDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                gTemplateLastRowc = gDataPaste.Cells(gDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
                
            Dim gFirstRow As Range
            Dim gLastRow As Range
                Set gFirstRow = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("COMBINED").Range("A" & fTemplateLastRowc)
                Set gLastRow = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("COMBINED").Range("A" & gTemplateLastRowb)
                Range(gFirstRow, gLastRow).Formula = "=concatenate(""Kroger YTD - Ending "",left(right('Weekly Division'!$A$4,24),23))"
    
    Workbooks("YTD Data.csv").Close SaveChanges:=False
    
'Stores Selling Summary Tab:
    'Remove Current Data
        Dim hDataPaste As Worksheet
            Set hDataPaste = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("stores selling summary")
        
        Dim hTemplateLastRow As Long
            hTemplateLastRow = hDataPaste.Cells(hDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
        Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("stores selling summary").Range("A6:N" & hTemplateLastRow).ClearContents
        
'Copy 52 Wk Data
    Workbooks.Open "O:\Wholesale\Reporting\Market6 Scorecard\Templates\Stores Selling 52 Wks.csv"
    
    Dim iStrData As Worksheet
    Dim iDataPaste As Worksheet
            Set iStrData = Workbooks("Stores Selling 52 Wks.csv").Worksheets("Stores Selling 52 Wks")
            Set iDataPaste = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("stores selling summary")
            
    Dim iTemplateLastRow As Long
    Dim iCopyLastRow As Long
            iTemplateLastRow = iDataPaste.Cells(iDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            iCopyLastRow = iStrData.Cells(iStrData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            
            iStrData.Range("A13:B" & iCopyLastRow).Copy iDataPaste.Range("B6:C" & iTemplateLastRow)
            iStrData.Range("C13:C" & iCopyLastRow).Copy iDataPaste.Range("G6:G" & iTemplateLastRow)
            iStrData.Range("F13:I" & iCopyLastRow).Copy iDataPaste.Range("I6:L" & iTemplateLastRow)
            iStrData.Range("D13:E" & iCopyLastRow).Copy iDataPaste.Range("M6:N" & iTemplateLastRow)
            
        'Add Dates
            Dim iTemplateLastRowb As Long
            Dim iTemplateLastRowc As Long
                iTemplateLastRowb = iDataPaste.Cells(iDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                iTemplateLastRowc = iDataPaste.Cells(iDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
                
            Dim iFirstRow As Range
            Dim iLastRow As Range
                Set iFirstRow = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("stores selling summary").Range("A6")
                Set iLastRow = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("stores selling summary").Range("A" & iTemplateLastRowb)
                Range(iFirstRow, iLastRow).Formula = "=concatenate(""Latest 52 Wks - Ending "",left(right('Weekly Division'!$A$4,24),23))"
                
    Workbooks("Stores Selling 52 Wks.csv").Close SaveChanges:=False
    
'Copy 26 Wk Data
    Workbooks.Open "O:\Wholesale\Reporting\Market6 Scorecard\Templates\Stores Selling 26 Wks.csv"
    
    Dim jStrData As Worksheet
    Dim jDataPaste As Worksheet
            Set jStrData = Workbooks("Stores Selling 26 Wks.csv").Worksheets("Stores Selling 26 Wks")
            Set jDataPaste = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("stores selling summary")
            
    Dim jTemplateLastRow As Long
    Dim jCopyLastRow As Long
            jTemplateLastRow = jDataPaste.Cells(jDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            jCopyLastRow = jStrData.Cells(jStrData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            
            jStrData.Range("A13:B" & jCopyLastRow).Copy jDataPaste.Range("B" & jTemplateLastRow)
            jStrData.Range("C13:C" & jCopyLastRow).Copy jDataPaste.Range("G" & jTemplateLastRow)
            jStrData.Range("F13:I" & jCopyLastRow).Copy jDataPaste.Range("I" & jTemplateLastRow)
            jStrData.Range("D13:E" & jCopyLastRow).Copy jDataPaste.Range("M" & jTemplateLastRow)
            
    'Add Dates
        Dim jTemplateLastRowb As Long
        Dim jTemplateLastRowc As Long
                jTemplateLastRowb = jDataPaste.Cells(jDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                jTemplateLastRowc = jDataPaste.Cells(jDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            
        Dim jFirstRow As Range
        Dim jLastRow As Range
                Set jFirstRow = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("stores selling summary").Range("A" & iTemplateLastRowc)
                Set jLastRow = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("stores selling summary").Range("A" & jTemplateLastRowb)
                Range(jFirstRow, jLastRow).Formula = "=concatenate(""Latest 26 Wks - Ending "",left(right('Weekly Division'!$A$4,24),23))"
                
    Workbooks("Stores Selling 26 Wks.csv").Close SaveChanges:=False
    
'Copy 13 Wk Data
    Workbooks.Open "O:\Wholesale\Reporting\Market6 Scorecard\Templates\Stores Selling 13 Wks.csv"
    
    Dim kStrData As Worksheet
    Dim kDataPaste As Worksheet
            Set kStrData = Workbooks("Stores Selling 13 Wks.csv").Worksheets("Stores Selling 13 Wks")
            Set kDataPaste = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("stores selling summary")
            
    Dim kTemplateLastRow As Long
    Dim kCopyLastRow As Long
            kTemplateLastRow = kDataPaste.Cells(kDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            kCopyLastRow = kStrData.Cells(kStrData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            
            kStrData.Range("A13:B" & kCopyLastRow).Copy kDataPaste.Range("B" & kTemplateLastRow)
            kStrData.Range("C13:C" & kCopyLastRow).Copy kDataPaste.Range("G" & kTemplateLastRow)
            kStrData.Range("F13:I" & kCopyLastRow).Copy kDataPaste.Range("I" & kTemplateLastRow)
            kStrData.Range("D13:E" & kCopyLastRow).Copy kDataPaste.Range("M" & kTemplateLastRow)
            
    'Add Dates
        Dim kTemplateLastRowb As Long
        Dim kTemplateLastRowc As Long
                kTemplateLastRowb = kDataPaste.Cells(kDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                kTemplateLastRowc = kDataPaste.Cells(kDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            
            Dim kFirstRow As Range
            Dim kLastRow As Range
                Set kFirstRow = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("stores selling summary").Range("A" & jTemplateLastRowc)
                Set kLastRow = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("stores selling summary").Range("A" & kTemplateLastRowb)
                Range(kFirstRow, kLastRow).Formula = "=concatenate(""Latest 13 Wks - Ending "",left(right('Weekly Division'!$A$4,24),23))"
                
    Workbooks("Stores Selling 13 Wks.csv").Close SaveChanges:=False

'Copy 4 Wk Data
    Workbooks.Open "O:\Wholesale\Reporting\Market6 Scorecard\Templates\Stores Selling 4 Wks.csv"
    
    Dim lStrData As Worksheet
    Dim lDataPaste As Worksheet
            Set lStrData = Workbooks("Stores Selling 4 Wks.csv").Worksheets("Stores Selling 4 Wks")
            Set lDataPaste = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("stores selling summary")
            
    Dim lTemplateLastRow As Long
    Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
            lTemplateLastRow = lDataPaste.Cells(lDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            lCopyLastRow = lStrData.Cells(lStrData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            
            lStrData.Range("A13:B" & lCopyLastRow).Copy lDataPaste.Range("B" & lTemplateLastRow)
            lStrData.Range("C13:C" & lCopyLastRow).Copy lDataPaste.Range("G" & lTemplateLastRow)
            lStrData.Range("F13:I" & lCopyLastRow).Copy lDataPaste.Range("I" & lTemplateLastRow)
            lStrData.Range("D13:E" & lCopyLastRow).Copy lDataPaste.Range("M" & lTemplateLastRow)
            
    'Add Dates
        Dim lTemplateLastRowb As Long
        Dim lTemplateLastRowc As Long
                lTemplateLastRowb = lDataPaste.Cells(lDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                lTemplateLastRowc = lDataPaste.Cells(lDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            
            Dim lFirstRow As Range
            Dim lLastRow As Range
                Set lFirstRow = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("stores selling summary").Range("A" & kTemplateLastRowc)
                Set lLastRow = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("stores selling summary").Range("A" & lTemplateLastRowb)
                Range(lFirstRow, lLastRow).Formula = "=concatenate(""Latest 04 Wks - Ending "",left(right('Weekly Division'!$A$4,24),23))"

    Workbooks("Stores Selling 4 Wks.csv").Close SaveChanges:=False
    
'Copy YTD Data
    Workbooks.Open "O:\Wholesale\Reporting\Market6 Scorecard\Templates\Stores Selling YTD.csv"
    
    Dim mStrData As Worksheet
    Dim mDataPaste As Worksheet
            Set mStrData = Workbooks("Stores Selling YTD.csv").Worksheets("Stores Selling YTD")
            Set mDataPaste = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("stores selling summary")
            
        Dim mTemplateLastRow As Long
        Dim mCopyLastRow As Long
            mTemplateLastRow = mDataPaste.Cells(mDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            mCopyLastRow = mStrData.Cells(mStrData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            
            mStrData.Range("A13:B" & mCopyLastRow).Copy mDataPaste.Range("B" & mTemplateLastRow)
            mStrData.Range("C13:C" & mCopyLastRow).Copy mDataPaste.Range("G" & mTemplateLastRow)
            mStrData.Range("F13:I" & mCopyLastRow).Copy mDataPaste.Range("I" & mTemplateLastRow)
            mStrData.Range("D13:E" & mCopyLastRow).Copy mDataPaste.Range("M" & mTemplateLastRow)
            
'Add Dates
    Dim mTemplateLastRowb As Long
    Dim mTemplateLastRowc As Long
                mTemplateLastRowb = mDataPaste.Cells(mDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                mTemplateLastRowc = mDataPaste.Cells(mDataPaste.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
                
        Dim mFirstRow As Range
        Dim mLastRow As Range
                Set mFirstRow = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("stores selling summary").Range("A" & lTemplateLastRowc)
                Set mLastRow = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("stores selling summary").Range("A" & mTemplateLastRowb)
                Range(mFirstRow, mLastRow).Formula = "=concatenate(""Kroger YTD - Ending "",left(right('Weekly Division'!$A$4,24),23))"
                
'Add Attributes where possible
    Dim nFirstRow As Range
    Dim nLastRow As Range
        Set nFirstRow = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("stores selling summary").Range("D6")
        Set nLastRow = Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("stores selling summary").Range("F" & mTemplateLastRowb)
        Range(nFirstRow, nLastRow).Formula = "=INDEX(COMBINED!$C:$F,MATCH($C6,COMBINED!$H:$H,0),MATCH(D$5,COMBINED!$C$4:$F$4,0))"
    
    Workbooks("Stores Selling YTD.csv").Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    'Calculate Workbook
    Calculate
    
    'Paste Values
    Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("COMBINED").Range("A5:U" & gTemplateLastRowb).Copy
    Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("COMBINED").Range("A5:U" & gTemplateLastRowb).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("stores selling summary").Range("A5:N" & mTemplateLastRowb).Copy
    Workbooks("KROGER M6 SCORECARD TEMPLATE.xlsm").Worksheets("stores selling summary").Range("A5:N" & mTemplateLastRowb).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
    'Save File as Template File
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
        
    'Turn on Screen Updates
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to CR! Does the actual complete code not fit in? Curious what `'Etc...` stands for - you'll get much better & thorough feedback if you include the whole module, including any `Option` and module-level declarations =)

Comment: Also, as noted in the [help] on "asking", please [edit] the title to give a brief summary of what the code does, not your goal in the code review (after all, everybody wants to "simplify" code or "make it run faster", those would be the title of nearly _every_ question here and _that_ would be confusing!). It's in the body of the question that you describe the improvements you're looking for. Also, as noted above, please give us _complete_, working routine(s) - it's very difficult to review bits and pieces.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thank you for welcome!  Sorry, I didn't know I could put the entire code in.  It has been updated.

Comment: @FreeMan Thank you for the feedback :) ... the Title and Code have been updated.